# How to change the app name in Ionic Version 1

Tags: eclipse, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I've changed the name in Confing.xml, after remove the android platform and again add the android platform, but still the app name doesn't change.

So, please tell me the possible solution to revoke this issue.

**String.xml**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<resources>
   <string name="app_name">Demo.app</string>
   <string name="launcher_name">@string/app_name</string>
   <string name="activity_name">@string/launcher_name</string>
</resources>
```

**Config.xml**

```
<widget id="com.demo.app" version="4.2.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
 <name>Demo.app</name>
 <description>It's a Business Process Management(BPM) app.</description>
```

Comment: The dot in the name may be breaking it, remove and try again

Comment: it is not the proper solution.

Comment: @ParthBhayani If  u have the app with the old name already try to uninstall it and reinstall the app again with the new name